# Adding sprite in Phaser js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I need to know how to add the 2nd, 3rd, 4th rows of this sprite image for the left, right and upwards(top) movement correspondingly.

Below code is for bottom movement and as its the first row in sprite, I am able to move it.

If I a create a long sprite horizontally I can achieve it, is there any other way?

Please  help me figure out  how to include the 2nd row onwards.

**Sprite image (user/player)** : [image: sprite image (user, player)]

```
function preload(){
    myGame.load.spritesheet('user', 'user4.png', 95, 158, 12);
}
var player;

function create(){
    player = myGame.add.sprite(500, 100, 'user');
    myGame.physics.arcade.enable(player);
    player.animations.add('bottom', [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 12, true, true);

}

function update(){
        if (cursors.left.isDown) {
            //  Move to the left
            player.body.velocity.x = -150;
            player.animations.play('left');
        }
        else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        {
            //  Move to the right
            player.body.velocity.x = 150;
            player.animations.play('right');
        }
        else if (cursors.up.isDown)
        {
            //  Move to the right
            player.body.velocity.y = -50;
            player.animations.play('top');
        }
        else if (cursors.down.isDown)
        {
            //  Move to the right
            player.body.velocity.y = 50;
            player.animations.play('bottom');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just define the extra animations the way you've done for bottom:

`player.animations.add('bottom', [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 12, true, true);
player.animations.add('left', [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 12, true, true);
player.animations.add('right', [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29], 12, true, true);`

And so on. Obviously I've just guessed the frame numbers above, you'll need to correct them to be whatever you actually need. But once you've done this, you can just call `play` on the animation keys.

Comment: This thing I tried before and I am getting error in console:

TypeError: frame is undefined
http://localhost/game/js/phaser.js
Line 31278

Is there a way to specify the starting x, y coordinates before this line:
player.animations.add('left', [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 12, true, true);

Comment: You are right, I think the problem is with the spritesheet I used in which the frames are not correct.

Comment: For `load.spritesheet` to work every single frame in the sheet must be the exact same size, with no extra padding at the sides of the sheet. If you would rather use different sized frames then you need to use a texture atlas instead, which may prove to be easier anyway - but it all depends what your source assets are like.

Comment: @photonstorm will mismatches between the size or number of sprites give an error or garbled frames?

Comment: @expiredninja depends on the mismatch. If it can't mathematically cut up the frames you'll get an error during loading. If it can, but the values don't accurately map to the actual sprite sheet you'll see corruption during playback of the animation.

Answer (score 3):

Change preload to this:

```
function preload() {
    game.load.spritesheet('user', 'user4.png', 95, 158, 48);
}
```

and add animation for all directions:

```
    player.animations.add('bottom', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 12, true, true);
    player.animations.add('left', [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], 12, true, true);
    player.animations.add('right', [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], 12, true, true);
    player.animations.add('top', [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47], 12, true, true);
```

Also remember to capture cursor inputs in your create() function:

```
    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
```

Tested it and made it work. Sprite sheet is not 100% correct, but it looks ok.

Answer (score 2):

to make things easy my approch is:

```
 animation_arr = ['idle', 'walk', 'jump', 'idle_towel', 'walk_towel', 'jump_towel' ];
 for(var i=0; i < animation_arr.length; i++){
    player.animations.add(animation_arr[i], [0+(i*10), 1+(i*10), 2+(i*10), 3+(i*10), 4+(i*10), 5+(i*10), 6+(i*10), 7+(i*10), 8+(i*10), 9+(i*10)], 10, true);
 }
```